# barousel navType 2 and 3 together

Tags: jquery, slider

```
        $('#barousel_thslide').barousel({
            navWrapper: '#thslide_barousel_nav .thslide_list',
            manualCarousel: 1,
            navType: 3
        });
        $('#barousel_thslide').barousel({
            navWrapper: '#barousel_prevnextnav .barousel_nav',
            manualCarousel: 1,
            navType: 2
        });
```

I want these two navigations interacted with each other when switching. Switching from one, and switching in other.